# Position of bootstrap's navbar-element

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap's navbar-element I need to put a welcome message in the center of my navbar. I'm using the following HTML structure from the bootstrap examples:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-5">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-5">
          <p class="navbar-text navbar-right welcome-message">Welcome, Tom Delonge</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

The name after 'Welcome' changes dynamicaly so I've added a little jQuery code to have it always centered:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var welcomeMessage = $('.welcome-message');
    var width = welcomeMessage.width();
    var offset = width / 2;
    welcomeMessage.css('margin-right', '-' + offset + 'px');
});
```

[FIDDLE Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/RxguB/50/)

I'm wondering if there is a better solution using only CSS for instance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove your javascript and replace css with this:

`.welcome-message {
    float: none !important;
    text-align: center;
}`

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

```
.welcome-message {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
 transform:translate(-50%,0);
}
```

> Just the above CSS will do the trick

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RxguB/51/)

Answer (score 1):

Restructure your class for `Welcome text` and add some custom CSS code for centering. No need for additional JS.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-5">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-5">
      <p class="navbar-text navbar-center welcome-message">Welcome, A very long name here</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar-collapse {
   text-align:center;
}
.navbar-center {
   display:inline-block;
   float:none;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/RxguB/52/)

Answer (score 1):

Add this css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 770px) {
    .welcome-message {
        margin-top: -35px;
        position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
 transform:translate(-50%,0);

}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 770px) {
    .welcome-message {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
 transform:translate(-50%,0);
}
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/RxguB/53/)**